# Express4 error middleware sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-4

Came accros a sequence of code execution which I found unusual here is the code:

**server.js**

```
const Actions_Single_PVC = require('./routes/Actions_single_PVC.js');

app.use('/Actions_single_PVC', Actions_Single_PVC);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {

    console.log('invalid token');

});
```

**Actions_single_PVC.js**

```
router.post('/', asyncMW(async (req, res, next) => {

throw new Error();

}));

router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log('error');
}
```

And in case you have never seen this construction before here is asyncMW:

```
const asyncMiddleware = fn =>
  (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
      .catch(next);
  };

  module.exports = asyncMiddleware;
```

What I didn't understand was that when an error is thrown (I reproduced it here with `throw new Error();`) that the error handling middleware in the  `server.js` file is executed. I expected that the error handling middleware of the  `Actions_single_PVC.js` would get executed.

### Question:

Why is the error middlware in `server.js` executed and not the error middlware in `Actions_single_PVC.js`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the following code applies middleware to only request with base path matching `Actions_single_PVC`.

```
app.use('/Actions_single_PVC', Actions_Single_PVC);
```

Whereas following code is apply middleware to all global requests.

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {

    console.log('invalid token');

});
```

If you'll hit the url `/Actions_single_PVC` then the middlewares in `Actions_single_PVC` will get hit.